# Verb for "to form the union of A and B"

Tags: single-word-requests

You can say *"to intersect A with B"* for *"to form the intersection of A and B"*.

But is there also a verb for *"to form the union of A and B"*? *"to unite A with B"* doesn't seem right, at least in the context of set theory.

Comment: *Unite* is perfectly correct.

Comment: Perhaps at [mathematics.se] this question might be better asked. There is a bit of difference in how mathematicians talk than general English. For instance, eschewing the conjugation of the verb, one might say, "And here, we take *A union B* and ..."

Comment: The mathematical operation ∪, as well as the act it performs, are both named "union". So, given "*operation*" in math corresponds to "*verb*" in grammar (some programming languages go so far as to call their functions "*verbs*"), I'm tempted to say the verb you want is "***to union***", as in "*Union A with B*".

Comment: @TobiasBrandt, done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mathematical operator ∪, as well as the act it performs, are both named "*union*".

So, given "*operation*" in math corresponds to "*verb*" in grammar (some programming languages go so far as to [call their functions "verbs"](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/partsofspeech.htm)), I'm tempted to say the verb you want is "***to union***", as in "*Union A with B*".

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by *the union*. There are several possible ways to join things. They may be

> - interleafed
> - concatenated
> - incorporated
> - merged
> - unified
> - homogenized
> - intermixed
> - coalesced
> - conflated
> - fused
> - mixed
> - commingled
> - blended
> - melded
> - combined
> - conjugated
> - admixed
> - accreted
> - alloyed
> - welded
> - consolidated

and many others.

Comment: Many others, including *joined*.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Yes, many, many.

Comment: I specifically mean the union of two sets, as in mathematics.

Comment: @TobiasBrandt Ask your math teacher.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if *"to unionize"* works, it means *"to place the members into a Union"* - but I've only seen it with Employees / Trade Unions.